# How to implement renderImage function

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, rscript

I am not able to upload the image through sub-directory path in shiny web page.

1. I created a sub-directory folder with the name "www" and put the image.
2. I have also tried by using URL.

Still not working

```
imageOutput("d", width = 300, height = 500)

output$d <- renderImage({ 
                        list(src= "driveaxle.png",
                        filetype = "image/png",
    )}), deletefile = False}
```

Comment: and with `deleteFile = FALSE` (capital letters) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Do you get an error message ? `False` must be `FALSE`, you have a comma to remove after `filetype`, and `deletefile` must be `deleteFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code. It need to modify few areas.
First you need to create a folder named as images under www folder. also you need to perse the filename from separate variable.

I tried and it looks like:
UI.R

```
fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      "This is Sidebar"
    ),
    mainPanel(imageOutput("d", width = 300, height = 500)
              )
  )
)
```

Server.R

```
function(input, output) {
  output$d <- renderImage({ 
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path('./www/images','studio logo.jpg'))

    list(src = filename,
         contentType = 'image/png',
         alt = "This is alternate text")
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)


  }
```

The output looks like:

[image]

You can read here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html